# What is the C# standard for capitialising method names?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

What is the C# standard for capitialising method names?  Is it:

```
MyClass.MyMethod()
```

or

```
MyClass.myMethod()
```

?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0.aspx

Comment: Incidentally, a very simple way to help remember this. The unity functions "Awake()" etc, are of course PascalCase in c# - so that's the answer.

Comment: This question is _not_ opinion based. Whether it's on topic is another question. I think it is, but the loud minority ("Meta") would say that it (as well as the _vast_ majority of questions on this "non Q&A site") is not.

Comment: There's absolutely no logical reason to use PascalCase instead of camelCase unless you want to use the presence of PascalCase to communicate some kind of semantic information. The only reason we even use camelCase is because we don't have the most natural word separator: ` `. That communication is a *flaw*, because you're using human convention to informally communicate something that should be machine-readable and automated: your code editor should be *automatically* visually distinguishing classes from instances. So this means that Microsoft have made **two** bad decisions in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The first one is right following the [.NET Capitalization Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions)

Comment: How do you tell the difference between nested inner classes and methods with this naming convention though? (A flaw perhaps?)

Comment: So it seems. I just quickly went through it now and I couldn't find an answer to your doubt.

Answer (score 44):

First one is standard in **C#**, second is standard in **Java**

Comment: The first one may be standard for C#, but I would say the second one is standard for pretty much every other language. Of the dozens of languages I know, I don't think any other language follows C#'s conventions. Most follow what Java does (although many of the languages predate Java.)

Comment: Coding conventions are inconsistent between multiple languages. The inconsistency is really a hindrance to those who code in several languages.

Answer (score 5):

C# Method are normally in PascalCase.  See the guidelines [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

**Microsoft recommend** to Use The first Approach.

Comment: Don't understand why microsoft would recommend first approach. I find method name starting with Captialize really not easy to read.  Its like writing a sentence, where each word is capitalized/

Comment: Do you know why though?

Answer (score 1):

[Pascal case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4df752aw%28VS.71%29.aspx) is the standard for .NET in general and C# in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe there is a standard, It's what ever you, and those you work with prefer. The most common i've seen is PascalCasing for Methods and Camel for private variables etc.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Naming standards say that you should use Pascal Case:

See [Method Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4df752aw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score -3):

Camel case vs proper case. The 100% Approved Right Way (TM) for C# is the latter.

Comment: You are incorrect (Assuming that your 'latter' refers to the original question).

Comment: I think you are confusing C# with Java 100%

Comment: "Assuming that your 'latter' refers to the original question" No, to the order in which I listed them.

Comment: well what is 'proper case' then?

Comment: Pascal case. My apologies if I call it something other than what's "correct". I meant no disrespect.